# Compare multiple Columns and Append the result into another file

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I have two files `file1` and `file2`, Both the files have `5 columns`.
I want to compare `first 4 columns` of `file1` with `file2`.

If they are equal, need to compare the `5th column`. If `5th column values` are different, need to print the `file1's 5th column` as `file2's 6th column`.

I have used below `awk` to compare  two columns in two different files, but how to compare multiple columns and append the particular column in another file if matches found?

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR{_1[$1]++;next}!_1[$1]'
```

file1:

```
111,item1,garde1,wing1,maingroup
123,item3,grade5,wing10,topcat
132,item2,grade3,wing7,middlecat
134,item2,grade3,wing7,middlecat
177,item8,gradeA,wing11,lowcat
```

file2:

```
111,item1,garde1,wing1,maingroup
123,item3,grade5,wing10,lowcat
132,item3,grade3,wing7,middlecat
126,item2,grade3,wing7,maingroup
177,item8,gradeA,wing11,lowcat
```

Desired output:

```
123,item3,grade5,wing10,lowcat,topcat
```

Comment: When writing software, it's generally accepted that it's a good idea to give variables meaningful names. `_1` would not qualify as such!

Answer (score 1):

Awk can simulate multidimensional arrays by sequencing the indices. Underneath the indices are concatenated using the built-in SUBSEP variable as a separator:

```
 $ awk -F, -v OFS=, 'NR==FNR { a[$1,$2,$3,$4]=$5; next } a[$1,$2,$3,$4] && a[$1,$2,$3,$4] != $5 { print $0,a[$1,$2,$3,$4] }' file1.txt file2.txt

123,item3,grade5,wing10,lowcat,topcat
```

`awk -F, -v OFS=,`

Set both input and output separators to `,`

`NR==FNR { a[$1,$2,$3,$4]=$5; next }`

Create an associative array from the first file relating the first four fields of each line to the
fifth. When using a comma-separated list of values as an index, awk actually concatenates them
using the value of the built-in SUBSEP variable as a separator. This is awk's way of
simulating multidimensional arrays with a single subscript. You can set SUBSEP to any value you like
but the default, which is a non-printing character unlikely to appear in the data, is usually
fine. (You can also just do the trick yourself, something like `a[$1 "|" $2 "|" $3 "|" $4]`,
assuming you know that your data contains no vertical bars.)

`a[$1,$2,$3,$4] && a[$1,$2,$3,$4] != $5 { print $0,a[$1,$2,$3,$4] }`

Arriving here, we know we are looking at the second file. If the first four fields were found in the
first file, and the $5 from the first file is different than the $5 in the second, print the line
from the second file followed by the $5 from the first. (I am assuming here that no $5 from the first file will have a value that evaluates to false, such as 0 or empty.)

Comment: Can you please explain.

Comment: You could make it shorter and more readable by using a variable to store the fields, also the next is redundant `awk -F, '{x=$1 $2 $3 $4}NR==FNR{a[x]=$5}a[x]&&a[x]!=$5{print $0,a[x]}'`

Comment: Sure, @Marjer, see the edit for additional comments.

Comment: This will fail if the 5th field contains a value that evaluates to numeric zero or is empty.

Comment: That's right, @EdMorton, and I did mention that in my extended comments. It seemed okay for this problem, but agree that it's a bad idea (and lazy of me) to put code out there that makes such assumptions.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that in your comment. It's just so easy to not write code with that caveat (use `x in y` instead of `y[x]`) it seems pointless to do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
{ key = $0; sub("(,[^,]*){"NF-4"}$","",key) }
NR==FNR { file1[key] = $5; next }
(key in file1) && ($5 != file1[key]) {
    print $0, file1[key]
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file1 file2
123,item3,grade5,wing10,lowcat,topcat
```